# Jersey HTTP authentication:How Can I Access and the HTTP authentication in jersey restful url?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am Writting a Restful webservice with Jersey, this is the sample code:

```
@GET
@Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String findItems(){

...
}
```

and the url of findItem is localhost:8080/items
the method should verify the  http authentication info(digest or basic) of this url before excutes,  how to access  authentication from the a url request first?

Answer (score 2):

I would not put this in the controller itself, but in a com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter around the resource classes you wish to protect, but should give you the basic idea.

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@GET
@Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String findItems(){
    String auth = request.getHeader("authorization");
    if (auth != null) {
        String basic_prefix = "Basic ";
        if (auth.startsWith(basic_prefix)) {
            String auth_data = new String(Base64.decode(auth.substring(basic_prefix.length())));
            String [] user_and_key = auth_data.split(":", 2);
            // user and password available here
        } else {
            // reject access
        }
    } else {
        // reject access
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.and Can you tell me how to access the digest authentication

Answer (score 0):

Usually the authentication is handled by the container, you just have to add the corresponding constraint to web.xml to indicate what Uris should be protected and what kind of auth is required. Then in jersey you can get the roles and principal info from the SecurityContext you can inject to your resource.